# Bent Metal on Light Fixture

Tags: metal, bathroom-fixtures

I recently bought a light fixture with a bent frame. Any ideas on how to bend the metal back to original shape without causing damage or discoloration to the metal?
[image]

Comment: Recently bought? Return it. The metal at the bend is now stretched, and shrinking it is a moderately high-skill job - doing so without affecting the finish is a moderately impossible job, unless you count "do the work, then refinish the whole thing."

Comment: If you can't return it....it goes in the dumpster.

Comment: As noted, you aren't going to bend it back to anything even remotely nice, so either return, dumpster, or bend the rest of it and call it art.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hacksaw, then maybe tin snips, to cut off the bent part. Drill some holes to move the lamp-heads to keep it as a 4-light unit or convert it to a 3-light unit. The open end could be filled with the old metal end, cut and screwed to fit.

Comment: I like the idea of reconfiguring it, but be aware that any modification voids the UL listing (and therefore transfers liability to the user).

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the electrical parts.

Get it straight (beat on it with a hammer etc)

Fill the dents with metal (solder or braze etc)

Get the surface flat (it needs to be very flat)

Re-chome or nickel plate it whatever the surface
finish is (send it to an electroplater)

Re-fit the electrical wiring.

It's probably cheaper to buy a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything from the frame, I'm assuming the frame is hollow. Cut a piece of wood to fit inside of the frame. Place another piece of wood on the outside and squeeze/pound together to straighten. Do the same on the sides if you have  creases there. If you need to get it straighter or remove creases check out some videos on using a hammer and dolly. I would avoid hitting the metal with a hammer, use a wood block and hit that with the hammer. If this fixture is installed on a ceiling you may not notice any creases or imperfections.